# .htaccess redirect / rewrite

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to redirect from:

domain.com/uploads/$

to

domain.com/download.php?file=$

$ being the variable.

I have tried many different ways but do not seem to be redirecting, I've tried, R=301,L,QSA and in various different orders.

Anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^uploads/(.*) /download.php?file=$1 [R=301]
```